# Impact of submitting Apps build in March 2024 with Xcode 14 and release it after April cut off

Tags: app-store, xcode14

If I use Xcode 14 to build our app and submit to test flight (not app store) on March and only release it to app Store in April. Will app store reject it since we didn't build it using Xcode 15?

> Please note that as of April 2024 all iOS and iPadOS apps submitted to
> the App Store must be built with a minimum of Xcode 15 and the iOS 17
> SDK.